# Web bluetooth characteristic data caching

Tags: web, bluetooth

I am trying to use web bluetooth with chrome on windows 10.  When I read the value from the characteristic I get the same data every time, which is incorrect.  I have used the same BLE hardware with a c# UWP application, and had the same results until I changed it to read with uncached mode.  So is there a way to not use cache mode for web bluetooth when reading the value from a characteristic?

The code below polls the characteristic every second.  This is a bluetooth thermometer, and the temp should change every time as the temp goes up and down.

```
ngOnInit() {
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{services: ['battery_service']}],
  optionalServices: ['f2b32c77-ea68-464b-9cd7-a22cbffb98bd']
})
  .then(device => device.gatt.connect())
  .then(server => {
    // Getting Temp Service...
    return server.getPrimaryService('f2b32c77-ea68-464b-9cd7-a22cbffb98bd');
  })
  .then(service => {
    // Getting Battery Level Characteristic...
    return service.getCharacteristic('78544003-4394-4fc2-8cfd-be6a00aa701b');
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    // Reading Battery Level...
    this.tempChar = characteristic;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.readOverAndOver(characteristic);
    }, 1000);

    return characteristic.readValue();
  })
  .then(value => {
    console.log('Battery percentage is ' + value.getUint8(0));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

readOverAndOver(characteristic: any) {
    const textEncoder = new TextDecoder();

```
this.tempChar.readValue().then(value => {
  const stringThing = textEncoder.decode(value);
  console.log(stringThing);
  console.log('new value: ', value);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may want to file this as a bug in Chrome at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry?components=Blink%3EBluetooth.